# C# seconds in string format to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, string, timespan

I'm having a bit of a issue with this.

What I want to do is take this string `27.0` and convert it to a timespan.

I tried every way I could think of in order to get it to work.

`TimeSpan.Parse("27.0")`  I know it's a format issue but I'm not sure of the format to use.

I basically have 4 values

`27.0`
`52.4`
`1:24.4`
`1:43.3`

Is there a easy way to handle all these formats?

Thanks!

Sorry these are all seconds except the 1 is minute so 1 minute 24 seconds 4 milliseconds

Comment: What is 27.0 supposed to be? Hours?

Comment: You can use one of the From* overloads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm assuming this is `minutes : seconds . split-seconds`

Comment: @Ben yesit is that way

Comment: `1:24.4` is "1 minute 24 seconds 4 milliseconds" should surely be **400** milliseconds (0.4 of a second)?

Comment: @Blorgbeard no the values represented with a 1: is a minute.... wt?

Comment: You said "Sorry these are all seconds except the 1 is minute so 1 minute 24 seconds **4 milliseconds**". You were referring to `1:24.4`, presumably. But `1:24.4` would normally be interpreted as 1 minute 24.4 seconds, not 1 minute 24.004 seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use two different approaches. Use one of the TimeSpan.From...() methods. Those convert numbers to a TimeSpan. For example to convert the double 27 to a TimeSpan with 27 seconds you use

```cs
var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(27)
```

The only problem you will face here is that it does not allow you to specify a string. So you could for example first parse your string as an double. If you do it naivly just like that, it can be you get what you wanted, or not.

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse("27.0"))
```

But if you run this for example on a system with a German locale you will get a TimeSpan with 4 minutes and 30 seconds. The reason for that is that a dot in German is not a divider for a number, it is the thousand seperator. So that number is parsed as "270". So to be safe you should also provide a NumberFormat. A better way would be.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var tsc = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse("27.0", culture.NumberFormat));
```

Now you get your 27 seconds. But the problem is still that it only parses your two first strings correctly. Your other 3 strings will still not parse, because you can't convert them to numbers. But I still added this, to be aware of culture difference if you just go up and try to parse a number to an double und use TimeSpan.FromSeconds() and so on.

Now lets look further how you can parse every string. There exists TimeSpan.Parse() and TimeSpan.ParseExact().

Now you still must knew that TimeSpan.Parse() uses culture specific formatting. In a country where a time is not separated with colons a TimeSpan.Parse() will fail. On Top of that, TimeSpan assumes a format "hh:mm" at minimum. But the Colon in this format is culture-sensitive. You could use the "en-US" Culture once again, but it wouldn't solve the problem because he doesn't accept the format "27.0".

That is the reason why you must use the TimeSpan.ParseExact() method and and provide the formats that this method should be able to parse. It also allows you to specify formats that he should be able to parse. You now should end with something like this.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var formats = new string[] {
    @"s\.f",
    @"ss\.f",
    @"ss\.ff",
    @"m\:ss\.f",
    @"m\:ss\.ff",
    @"mm\:ss\.ff"
};
foreach ( var str in new string[] { "27.0", "52.4", "1:24.4", "1:43.3" } ) {
    var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(str, formats, culture.NumberFormat);
    Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
}
```

Note that in this example I added a backslash to escape the dot and the colon. If you don't do this then the formatter itself treats this as a culture-sensitive separator. But what you want is exactly the colon or the dot.

The output of this code will be

```
00:00:27
00:00:52.4000000
00:01:24.4000000
00:01:43.3000000
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
var timeString = "1:24.4";

var timeComponents = timeString.Split(':', '.').Reverse().ToList();

var milliseconds = timeComponents.Any() ? int.Parse(timeComponents[0]) : 0;
var seconds = timeComponents.Count() > 1 ? int.Parse(timeComponents[1]) : 0;
var minutes = timeComponents.Count() > 2 ? int.Parse(timeComponents[2]) : 0;

var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

this will deal with the milliseconds literally. You may want to pad the string component of the milliseconds with '0's, as pointed out in the comments.